# Different printing behavior of Raspberry vs Ubuntu using a Dymo LabelWriter and a PostScript file

Tags: ubuntu, cups

I'm defining a PostScript file as a template to then use it as a base to print labels. For this I was using my Ubuntu desktop, but when I tried to print the same PostScript file on the Raspberry, I get completely different font size, offsets, etc.

The printer is a Dymo LabelWriter 550 Turbo.

The Drivers used are exactly the same. The official drivers that you can find on GitHub, compiled and installed.

So far, I have discovered that the "default options" in the CUPS interface will have great impact, even if I try to override them with the `lpr` command and/or the PostScript file itself.

However, even with the exact same CUPS configuration and the exact same PostScript file, I get different results when printing from the Ubuntu desktop vs the Raspberry Pi.

Are not PostScript files supposed to stay the same like PDF?